# Subclipse - Checkout lacking root directory

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

We just implemented SVN usage at our office and the other dev and myself are both running duplicate versions of eclipse, subclipse, and a few required/optional elements.  They're all the same versions and everything.

I can do a checkout just fine because the checkout directory I can select is the root, whereas he doesn't see the root as an option as a folder to checkout.  He can only checkout individual folders, not the root.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the hypothetical SVN base urls you are both pointed at?

For instance https://server/project/? If he is pointed at https://server/project/root and you are just https://server/project/ that would be why.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess... No access rights because of SVN server has path-based security enabled and he has no access rights to the root?

Could you try to set your username and password in his environment to check if this is the case?